# Flutter Firebase phone authentication error

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication, sms-verification

**I am trying to implement phone auth using firebase but error occurs after I input the number it never sends the otp and stays in the same screen and I get this errors in my terminal.**

*1)  SMS verification failed*

E/FirebaseAuth(18472): [SmsRetrieverHelper] SMS verification code request failed: unknown status

*2) Verify package name and sha fingerprints*

code: 17028 Invalid request fields in play_integrity_token
D/FirebaseAuth(18472): Invoking original failure callbacks after phone verification failure for +917558480404, error - This app is not authorized to use Firebase Authentication. Please verify that the correct package name, SHA-1, and SHA-256 are configured in the Firebase Console. [ Invalid request fields in play_integrity_token ]

**As given in the second error I rechecked all the fields in my firebase console the package name and SHA fingerprints they are correct according to my project still the same error occurs**

**I tried by adding a test phone number and otp in my firebase console and it works my app runs correctly but it gives error if I try with a different phone number**

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is due to some change in sha256 keys. Please verify if you have added both the debug and play auth keys in your Firebase app.